# How to create Menu with onPress attribute of TouchableOpacity

Tags: typescript, react-native, touchableopacity

I want a profile picture uploading with the options: get image from camera (call getMediaFromCamera) on press or get image from gallery (getMediaFromImageLibrary)
I have a TouchableOpacity but I want to create a menu when clicking so that the user can select the method. Do I need a menu or can this be done inside touchableopacity

```
    <View style={imageUploaderStyles.uploadBtnContainer}>
    <TouchableOpacity
      onPress={getMediaFromCamera}
      style={imageUploaderStyles.uploadBtn}>
      <Text>
        {props.profile_photo
          ? Language.PersonalInformation.change_photo
          : Language.PersonalInformation.add_photo}{' '}
      </Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  </View>
```

I want something like below to popup when the user presses.

[image]

Comment: try this library https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-floating-action

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://docs-v2.nativebase.io/Components.html#accordion-def-headref and put these touchableopacities inside that component.